# Comparison of Entropy and Distribution of Bytes in Compressed/Encrypted Data

Tags: statistics, distribution, entropy, chi-squared

I have some question which occupies myself for a while.

The entropy test is often used to identify encrypted data. The entropy reaches its maximum when the bytes of the analyzed data are distributed uniformely. The entropy test identifies encrypted data, because this data has a uniform distribution - like compressed data, which is classified as encrypted when using the entropy test.

Example: The entropy of some JPG file is 7,9961532 Bits/Byte, the entropy of some TrueCrypt-container is 7,9998857. This means with the entropy test I cannot detect a difference between encrypted and compressed data. BUT: as u may see on the first picture, obviously the bytes of the JPG-file are not distributed uniformely (at least not as uniform as the bytes from the truecrypt-container).

Another test can be the frequency analysis. The distribution of each byte is measured and e.g. a chi-square test is performed to compare the distribution with a hypothetic distribution. as a result, I get a p-value. when i perform this test on JPG and TrueCrypt-data, the result is different.

The p-Value of the JPG file is 0, which means that the distribution from a statistical view is not uniform. The p-Value of the TrueCrypt-file is 0,95, which means that the distribution is almost perfectly uniform.

My question now: Can somebody tell me why the entropy test produces false positives like this? Is it the scale of the unit, in which the information content is expressed (bits per byte)? Is e.g. the p-value a much better "unit", because of a finer scale?

Thank you guys very much for any answer/ideas!

EDIT: Unfortunately I cannot post images because I havent got 10 reputations yet :(

Comment: Can you provide a link to a definition of the "entropy test" that you're using?

Comment: Also, this is off-topic.  It may be better to ask at http://crypto.stackexchange.com.

Comment: since it handles measuring of compression, it does not only apply to crypto stackechange.

Comment: To measure compression rate and random variables i only heard thath the chi square is the recommended one.

Comment: For the entropy, I calculate the probability each number (0-255) appears. then i sum up all log(probability) and have the entropy.

software like encase, which is used for forensic examination, uses the entropy for detecting encrypted data. but as you can see, the entropy leads to many false positives. other approaches, like the chi square, have much better results. but the two tests are used for the same thing, detecting the uniformation of bytes. how the result can be so different?

Comment: @AlexWien: Maybe you're right.  So http://stats.stackexchange.com instead?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth neither stats nor maths, this is a topic that people like i have learned when they studied computer science. advanced sw development needs mathematics and sometimes statistics. and entropie is a term used in software theory. for me its ok to post that in alle 3: here, maths and stats

Comment: @AlexWien: This is a pure theory question, not a programming question.  So as interesting a question as it is, it's off-topic here.

Comment: I think its likely you are calculating the entropy incorrectly but without any details or examples it is difficult to say. You say you are summing log probability - you should be taking the expectation of log(p) (ie sum(p log p) ) which is one thing...

Comment: thanks guys, [i moved this topic to stats.stackexchange.com](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/49117/comparison-of-entropy-and-distribution-of-bytes-in-compressed-encrypted-data)

Comment: @robince, thank you! my description was wrong, but I calculated the entropy as u explained... sum(p log p).

Comment: Why don't you show code? I think it is likely there is an error in how you are comuting the entropy.

Comment: You should probably be reading the NIST Special Publication 800-22, A Statistical Test Suite for Random and Pseudorandom Number Generators for Cryptographic Applications, at http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/nistpubs/800-22-rev1a/SP800-22rev1a.pdf.

Comment: Check this PDF: https://www.defcon.org/images/defcon-21/dc-21-presentations/Ortiz/DEFCON-21-Ortiz-Fast-Forensics-Using-Simple-Statistics-and-Cool-Tools.pdf , especially pages 38 and 39. It doesn't answer your question but gives a good overview of the topic.